# Teamsite Folder

Tags: teamsite

Is there a command-line utility to create folders/sub-folders inside a workarea in Teamsite?

I went through a list, and all it seems to contain were those concerning creation/modification of groups/branches and related permissions.

Answer (score 1):

the folders and files are standard system files and folders, so you use standard command line tools (CLTs) to do what you want.

for example in windows, you'd use DOS command 'mkdir ' to create a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be a command by which we can create files and folders inside a Workarea.
Since, to some extent Branches, Workareas etc are customizable and can be created through command-line tool (CLT) instead of TeamSite UI. Even through command line tool we can easily fetch number of branches, workareas etc present in a particular branch. You can refer to "*WebContentManagement_CommandLineTools_en.pdf*" for the same and check inside workarea section the list of commands.
Please vote the solution if its helpful. Thanks!